# Error in simple SQL when executing in python

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm getting an error with this SQL code when I execute it in my Flask app. I swear I've done this exact thing before and it worked, so I'm not sure what's happening.

Here is the SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;

CREATE TABLE order (
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    plan_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    placed TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ssh_key TEXT NOT NULL,
    region INTEGER NOT NULL,
    operating_system INTEGER NOT NULL,
    enable_ipv6 INTEGER NOT NULL
    expires INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Here is the relevant part of my python error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "order": syntax error
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order is a reserved keyword for sqlite. If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it.
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html